# Выбор частицы НЕ или НИ в заданном тексте

Tags: пунктуация, орфография, частица-не

Мне недавно встретился в Интернете такой стихотворный текст:

*Не пиши, не пиши ты мне писем, пожалуйста,*

*Дело есть, но его между нами не высказать.*

***Я тебе не отвечу, ни из милости, ни из жалости,***

*Я давно не писал ничего, кроме формул и выкладок…*

Вроде бы это старая студенческая песня, то ли физиков, то ли летчиков.  Меня же заинтересовал выбор **частицы  НИ** в обособленном обороте, а также необходимость **обособления** этого оборота.

Варианты с другими решениями действительно нашлись – это отрицательная частица НЕ и отсутствие обособления. Соответственно, возникли **такие вопросы:**

(1) Выбор НЕ  вроде бы можно объяснить по контексту,  но возможно ли здесь усиление с частицей НИ?

(2) Оба ли варианта допустимы, меняется ли смысл при этом?

(3)  Нужно ли обособлять оборот?

Было бы интересно услышать ваше мнение.

Спасибо.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Я добавлю в вопрос информацию из комментария (в чем мои сомнения)

Сначала я решила, что правильный выбор – это только НЕ, а НИ – речевая ошибка.  Потом стала думать, что НИ тоже возможно, но **смысл** меняется. Но вот как меняется? Тогда я подумала, что там только смысловые **оттенки** разные. Но опять же надо указать, в чем их разница?

Что касается **взаимозаменяемости** НЕ и НИ, то я помню **один пример** на эту тему, но хотелось бы, чтобы их было побольше (чтобы сделать вывод).

И по поводу обособления. Я считала, что обособление – это всего лишь выделение (актуализация) оборота, а теперь мне кажется, что в случае  использования НИ обособление **обязательно**. Появились подозрения на **лексическую несочетаемость** оборота.

Comment: ни = и не. "Ни одно, ни другое" = "И не одно и не другое". "Ни то, ни се" = "И не то, и не се". "Ни из-за милости, ни из-за жалости" = "И не из-за милости, и не из-за жалости". Всякие там усиления и прочая стилистика легко добиваются контекстом, интонацией, ударением. Либо можно назвать это громким словом: усиливающая частица.

Comment: А вы не могли бы дать ответ на три моих вопроса точно по их тексту, примерно по такому плану: (1) оба варианта допустимы,  (2) смысловая раница заключается в следующем... И т.д. И всё-таки не в комментрии, а в поле  ответа.

Comment: Ну я же, фактически, дал. Еще раз: (1) Оба допустимы. (2) Разница если и есть, то только стилистическая и легко нивелируется конткестом, интонацией, ударением. (3) смысл не меняется, меняется оттенок и то см (2). (4) - не знаю, поэтому и не стал оформлять ответ.

Comment: А почему возможно как усиление, так и отрицание? Эти частицы  не так часто заменяют друг друга . Например: На небе ни облачка.  Он не умел ни читать, ни писать. Вы можете привести пример другого текста, где также возможна замена. Разный стиль? Нейтральный и разговорный или как? Не очень ясно. К сожалению, вы уходите от точной терминологии. А  на интонацию выбор частицы не влияет (влияет только обособление).

Comment: Да, я знал, что замена не всегда работает, но поленился искать для себя примеры. Теперь ваш вопрос становится для меня более содержательным. Сформулировать критерий замены ни на не.

Comment: Спасибо. Я вижу, что он никому не показался особо содержательным :) Сначала я решила, что правильный выбор – это только НЕ. Потом стала думать, что НИ тоже возможно, но смысл меняется. Но как меняется? Тогда я подумала, что там только смысловые оттенки разные. Но опять же надо указать, в чем их разница?  Что касается замены НЕ и НИ, то я помню один пример на эту тему,  но хотелось бы, чтобы их было побольше.

Comment: *Вроде бы это старая студенческая песня, то ли физиков, то ли летчиков* — цитирую вопрос. Там действительно нужна запятая?

Comment: Артем, а почему вам не нравится?. Обособление определительного оборота по желанию автора. Я решила придать ему уточняющее значение, пауза в устной речи. Для обособления оборота в конце предложения часто используется тире, но здесь союзная связь.

Comment: Спасибо, что объяснили. Нет, нравится, просто хотел убедиться, что у вас такой именно смысл и что тут действительно возможны два варианта. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ПРАВИЛО (**ни..ни..** это строго усилительная, а не отрицательная констуркция)

Двойной союз **ни..ни..**
Работает строго как усиление в общеотрицательных (уже с одним не), или частноотрицательных (тоже уже с одним не) предложениях. § 2663
(Из этого, кстати, вытекает 99% синонимичность и..и.. с ни.. ни..)
http://rusgram.narod.ru/2661-2673.html

ПРИМЕРЫ

1. `Я тебе не отвечу не под пыткой и не под кайфом. Под пыткой или кайфом я отвечу (возможно).` Двойное отрицание = отсутствие отрицания.
2. `Я тебе отвечу не под пыткой и не под кайфом. Под пыткой или кайфом я не отвечу (возможно).`. Одинарное отрицание.
3. Чтобы избежать двойного отрицания, можно использовать 2, либо использовать союз ни..ни.. (синоничный в данном случае и..и..). `Я тебе не отвечу ни под пыткой, ни под кайфом. Под пыткой или кайфом я не отвечу.`. Одинарное отрицание.
4. `Я тебе отвечу ни под пыткой, ни под кайфом.`. Ошибка. В предложении
   нет ни одного "не".

ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЯ (**ни** иногда все-таки отрицательная)

1. § 2663.
   В предложениях без отрицания при узком круге глаголов употребляются лексикализованные сочетания ни с чем, ни за что, форма ничем: остаться, уйти ни с чем; пропасть, погибнуть ни за что; кончиться ничем: `На этот раз ему не повезло, и он вернулся с охоты ни с чем` ; `Люди вы свои, и мне жалко, коли вы пропадете ни за что`.
2. В позиции сказуемого или главного члена предложения нормальны также лексические фразеологизмы с ни: `Урожай тут ни при чем`
3. В позиции разных членов предложения употребляются организуемые союзом ни...ни сочетания противоположных по значению слов. Элемент ни при этом относится только к словоформе, которой непосредственно предшествует, и имеет значение частного отрицания: `Она сыграла ни хорошо, ни плохо. Он ушел ни потому, ни поэтому.`

АНАЛИЗ НАШЕГО ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ

```
Я не отвечу вам не из жалости, не из милости.     // Из жалости или из милости я могу ответить, а так не могу. Двойное отрицание. Решение неопределенно. Но это не страшно, по контексту все очевидно.

Я не отвечу вам, причем не из жалости, не из милости.     // Жалости или милость не влияют на мое решение. Оно отрицательно. 

Я не отвечу вам, ни из жалости, ни из милости, ни по чему либо еще.    // Из жалости или милость не влияют на мое решение. Оно отрицательно. См. 3-й пункт исключений. 

Я не отвечу вам ни по жалости, ни по милости.     // Я не отвечу вам и по жалости, и по милости. Одинарное отрицание.
```

ИТОГОВЫЙ ОТВЕТ

Думаю, возможны обе конструкции со сходным смыслом. Но обе опираются на контекст.

```
Я тебе не отвечу, ни из милости, ни из жалости.
```

Здесь нам обязательно требуется противопоставление, как в предложении **Я тебе не отвечу, ни потому, ни поэтому.**. Если контекст задает это противопоставление, то никаких проблем я не вижу.

```
Я тебе не отвечу не из милости, не из жалости.
```

Здесь двойное отрицание делает возможным экзотическую трактовку. Но такая трактовка исключается внешней средой.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ о примерах **ни..ни..** в отрицательной функции.

В словосочетаниях (ответах, заголовках) и целостных словосочетаниях внутри предложения **ни** используется как **не**, но только при условии двойного союза.

```
Ты не ушел и не убежал?
- Ни ушел, ни убежал.

Ты не ушел и не убежал?
"Ни ушел, ни убежал" - это сильно сказано.

Он был ни то, ни се.
Он был не то, не се.
```

Comment: Большое спасибо вам за участие в обсуждении  и за ваш ответ.  Я прокомментирую его позже в таком формате: дам свой ответ в общем плане, а также отдельный комментарий по вашему ответу. Правда,  это займет некоторое время, так как надо всё хорошо обдумать.

Answer (score 3):

> Я тебе не отвечу, ни из милости, ни из жалости.

Первое отрицание (*не отвечу*) исключает дальнейшее НЕ, тем более повторяющееся. Однако автором фраза разбивается надвое запятой, что выводит конструкцию из этого правого поля. К тому же близкая по смыслу пара *милость*/*жалость* — совсем не образец противопоставления, которое характерно для выражения категоричной мысли, где *ни то, ни другое* всегда означает *ничто*.

> И вот мне не любы Ни солнце, ни месяц высокий, Никому не нужны мои
> губы И бледные щеки. [С. К. Маковский. Николай Гумилев (1886-1921)
> (1961-1962)]
>
> На стогах лежал волшебный снег, способный выбелить любую холстину так,
> как не умеют ни солнце, ни зола. [Наталья Галкина. Вилла Рено //
> «Нева», 2003]

У фразы мог бы быть формат с тире перед пояснительными словами: *я тебе не отвечу — не из милости, не из жалости*.

> Это тебе геометрия нужна будет в жизни ― не мне, не учителю. [Михаил
> Гиголашвили. Чертово колесо (2007)]
>
> Ты не мне, не себе ― своим товарищам вредишь, я вам уже тысячу раз это
> говорила. [Алексей Иванов. Географ глобус пропил (2002)]

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение. Дело в том, что нужно рассматривать весь контекст. Выбор НЕ определяется по скрытому противопоставлению: Не отвечу не из милости, не из жалости, а потому что давно вообще ничего не писал (не было времени, так что и слова-то  отвык писать).  Такая трактовка при выбор НЕ кажется вполне обоснованной.

Comment: Спасибо за вопрос и текст. Есть такой в сети 1-й куплет... =====    Я прошу, не пиши ты мне писем, пожалуйста, 
Дело есть и его я ей-богу, не выдумал. 
Я тебе не отвечу, не из милости и не из жалости, 
Я давно не писал ничего, кроме формул и выводов.

Comment: Да, здеь рифма правильная. Спасибо вам еще раз, я завтра  что-нибудь напишу еще по теме, вы мне очень помогли.

Comment: Тоже сейчас думал об этом вопросе и только сейчас прочитал ответ. Спасибо, Sharon,  спасибо,  shampar.

Comment: Спасибо  и  вам...

Answer (score 1):

Мне  казалось, что я неплохо разбираюсь в теме, но всё-таки в этом случае были определенные затруднения. Поэтому я еще раз благодарю участников, которые помогли мне прояснить некоторые спорные моменты.

**1. О грамматике усилительных конструкций**

Нормой  является строгость усилительной отрицательной конструкции: в предложении должно быть выражено отрицание (частица НЕ), которое в нем же усиливается (частица НИ, союз НИ…НИ).

Все отклонения от нормы  (НИ без НЕ) каким-то образом  должны **объясняться:**

(1) Слово с пропущенной частицей  НЕ можно легко **восстановить**: *А в сердце ни искры отрады, и нечем прогнать эту мглу. Ни в сказке сказать, ни пером описать.*

(2) **При полноте отрицания**  отрицаются два признака, предмета или действия, но подразумевается полное отрицание всех других возможных признаков, предметов и действий. Это тот случай, когда частица НИ одновременно имеет значение и отрицания и усиления: *Ворон ни варят, ни жарят.*

(3) **Устойчивые сочетания.** В этом случае усилительная конструкция не  строится  в данном предложении, а используется как отдельный структурный элемент: *Вот и полночь наступила, у него в груди заныло: он ни жив ни мертв лежит. Тянет стужей, пахнет дымом, ну овин – ни дать ни взять. И вдруг говорят ни с того ни с сего, что примет он смерть от коня своего.*

**2.  О грамматике заданного предложения**

Из общего грамматического материала ясно, что при наличии отрицания «не отвечу» нормой является использование усилительной **частицы НИ**, так как предложение нельзя отнести к исключениям.

Но тогда вариант с НЕ можно использовать только **в обособленном виде**, в то время как вариант с НИ можно и не обособлять.  С другой стороны,  указание на причину действия  желательно как-то в тексте подчеркнуть (обособление желательно в обоих случаях).

Соответственно,  грамматически верными нужно считать **три варианта.** Какой выбрать? Пожалуй, выберем вариант **с обособлением и частицей НЕ**, чтобы обозначить противопоставление:

*Не пиши, не пиши ты мне писем, пожалуйста,*

*Дело есть, но его между нами не высказать.*

*Я тебе не отвечу, не из милости, не из жалости,*

*Я давно не писал ничего, кроме формул и выводов…*

**В  качестве дополнительного материала**

1. В ответе было сказано, что **содержание текста** понятно, но мне выраженная здесь семантика не представляется вполне очевидной. Представьте, что вы получаете такое сообщение (хотя оно и вряд ли будет послано, это скорее мысли вслух). Вам всё будет понятно, разберетесь во всех этих НЕ и НИ.

*Я тебе не отвечу из жалости*? Обычно из жалости всё-таки отвечают. Здесь, правда,  отрицание: *Я тебе не отвечу не из жалости, а по другой причине*. Так о какой жалости он говорит? Вероятно, нечем ему ответить на чувства (на это и намекает), поэтому лучше вообще промолчать, вас жалеючи. (Не получал как бы ничего, вот и не ответил.)  Соответственно, логика здесь плохо помогает, а вот чувства угадываются лучше. И они всё-таки **позитивные…**

2. Конечно, мне трудно обойтись **без художественного анализа стихотворения**. Честно говоря, не орфография мне показалась привлекательной, а само четверостишие. Вроде бы любительская поэзия, но какая-то пронзительно-эмоциональная… Тема давно известная, еще Тютчев говорил: *«Silentium! Как сердцу высказать себя? Другому как понять тебя? Поймет ли он, чем ты живешь? Мысль изреченная есть ложь*». И конечно Мандельштам: «*Да обретут мои уста Первоначальную немоту, Как кристаллическую ноту, Что от рождения чиста*!»

Глубокая философская лирика, красивый и загадочный символизм – разве можно это сравнивать с песенной поэзией? Но уже отмечалось, что иногда **самые простые формы** волнуют нас не меньше, чем формы изысканные. Случайно ли это? Думаю, что нет, и вот бы разгадать этот секрет! Или хотя бы понять отдельные приемы, которыми поэты, скорее всего,  пользуются интуитивно. Но  там же вдохновение, музы, крылатые Пегасы!  А вот можно ли этим управлять намеренно?

**Согласно последним научным сведениям**,  в нашем понимании сознания произошла смена парадигмы – сознание как основа  бытия, а не наоборот. Теперь «наше настоящее я» мыслится вне нас, а весь организм воспринимается как нечто целое. Физиология, эмоции и мысли жестко связаны между собой, а для их управления используются «паттерны» – определенные ментальные цепочки. Если вы часто думаете о чем-то, то возникает устойчивость этой связи, а активироваться она может любым способом. Вот такая «забавная» теория. Получается, что надо найти **ключ к активации прекрасного,**  тогда даже простая мысль засияет всеми красками. **Поэты,  вы меня слышите?** (Извините, это шутка.)

Об этом я думала, когда читала эти стихи – что же в них необыкновенного? Перед нами современный вариант «Silentium!»?

Прежде всего,  **сюжетная лирика** – она более конкретная, более чувственная и эмоциональная, поэтому не так холодна, как философские рассуждения.

И еще скрытая **напряженность, недосказанность, сдержанность** – тоже приметы нашего времени, но одновременно это  известный магический прием, повышающий энергетику.

**Движение** как антипод неподвижности, но как его создать? Смешение стилей – вот известный метод, еще Пушкин пользовался. Разговорный вариант "дело есть" – и  книжное «высказать», которое и у Тютчева присутствует. И повтор отрицательных частиц – сознание как бы скользит по ним.

**Звучная перекрестная рифма** (пожалуйста – из жалости) как центр высказывания  – она тоже очень лиричная и трогательная, а рядом с «дело есть»  кажется просто головокружительной, так что вторая рифма  как бы и не нужна.

Вот такие отдельные замечания, может быть, можно увидеть еще что-то. Спасибо вам за внимание.

Comment: Наконец-то прочитал этот/эту/это... (Круговерть  названий не дает выбрать верное.)  Супер!

Comment: Спасибо за вашу оценку, меня всегда очень интересует ваше мнение.